# wxPython StyledTextCtrl, weird 'LF'

Tags: python, wxpython, scintilla

I am working on a simple text editor in wxPython, and I noticed a problem:
When I press 'Return' key, editor adds a weird 'LF':

[image: How do i remove them?]

How do i prevent my program from printing them?

Comment: Could you post relevant portions of your code for us to take a look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem was:
I had that line in my custom StyledTextCtrl subclass:

```
self.SetViewEOL(True)
```

It was causing printing of those 'LF's

Here is the function's description:

```
SetViewEOL(self, bool visible)

Make the end of line characters visible or invisible.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows then carriage return is actually Carriage Return, Line Feed, (0x0a, 0x0d) - (on old Macs it is the other way round) - you are probably just stripping off the last character line.strip() should get rid of it or you can search for and replace chr(0x0a) and chr(0x0b) with '' in your strings.